# docker track logs from dynamically created containers

Tags: docker, logging

I have an app that is dynamically creating docker containers and I can't intercept the way it is created.

I want to see logs from all the machines that are up. no matter if it was via docker-compose or just docker command line. I need to see all the logs.

Is it possible?

right no I need to run `docker ps`, see all the created machines and run `docker log container`.

I can't really monitor what is going inside.

Thanks

Comment: Just an idea...... i have the same issue couple of weeks before, i wanted to see all the logs simultaneously, For this i have created a web page where all the docker container IDs are being listed and every ID is hyperlinked to another page, that is showing the logs of that container. In this way you can monitor multiple containers and their logs easily. I have achieved this task using Python-Flask.

Answer (score 0):

An approach is to use a dedicated logging container that can gather log events from other containers, aggregate them, then store or forward the events to a third-party service, this approach eliminates the dependencies on a host.
Further, dedicated logging containers can automatically collect, monitor, and analyze log events, It can scale your log events automatically without configuration. It can retrieve logs through multiple streams of log events, stats, and Docker API data. 
You can check this link also for some help.

[Docker Logging Best Practices](http://www.monitis.com/blog/containers-5-docker-logging-best-practices/)